# IIS 7.5 images not showing - 404

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, image

I have IIS 7.5 running my local dev site. My problem is the images are not displaying and in the browser console i receive a 404 error for them. I have checked the Handler Mappings and have 'StatticFile'. I've also got Common Http features, and checked "Static Content".

Can anyone help with my problem please?

**EDIT**

Heres a line from my log file in inetpub:

```
2014-09-16 08:21:38 127.0.0.1 GET /images/eclipse/favicon.ico - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/37.0.2062.120+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 4
```

**EDIT** 
what the console in the browser displays:

```
GET https://www.dev.mysite.net.uk/images/eclipse/spacer.gif 404 (Not Found) index.cfm?id=myeclipse&relocate=1:449
```

Comment: is this just affecting favicon files or all images?

Comment: @rob both favicon and all images

Comment: add a robots.txt or similar plain text file to the root can you browse to that? Then try the same with an image in root.

Comment: @rob yes i can navigiate to both an image and text file fine when placing them in the root

Comment: Have you checked the NTFS permissions on the problem directory? Compare them to a directory from which you can serve files of the same type. Also, I hope that the log file entry and the browser console entry do not refer to the same request.

Comment: I would try creating a new folder and putting a single image and testing the browser against that.